# Store pointer inside NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsnumber, nsurlprotocol

I implementing custom subclass of the `NSURLProtocol`. I need to store my `NSURLProtocol` instance inside `NSMutableURLRequest`. Since `[NSURLProtocol setProperty:forKey:inRequest:]` raises warning `Invalid protocol-property list` if you try to store non-plist-serializable object, I do it like this:

```
- (void)startLoading {
    ...    
    // when I need to store an NSURLProtocol subclass
    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long)self] forKey:@"WebProxyURLProtocol" inRequest:mutableRequest];
    ...
}
```

and

```
// when I need to get an NSURLProtocol subclass back in NSURLSessionDelegate
- (NSURLProtocol *)protocolForTask:(NSURLSessionTask *)task {
    NSNumber *number = [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"WebProxyURLProtocol" inRequest:task.originalRequest];
    return (__bridge NSURLProtocol *)(void *)number.longLongValue;
}
```

This works quite well. But is it safe and correct way to solve my problem, or I sometimes can get already deallocated object? Thanks!

Comment: It is extremely not safe. Why you can't use `registerClass:` and `canInitWithRequest:` methods?

Comment: Or why you can't use Factory pattern here?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov You have misunderstood me. I call [NSURLProtocol setProperty:forKey:inRequest:] in [NSURLProtocol startLoading]. I need to call [NSURLProtocol client]'s methods from NSURLSessionDelegate in another place.